# Javascript fetch() function doesn't work on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple code that asks the program to fetch some data using fetch() when I click the button:

```
<button id="hello-btn">Say Hello!</button>
<script>
    var route = "/a-url";
    let fetch_data = (route) => {
        fetch(route)
            .then(res => res.text())
            .then(data => $("#resp").text(data))
    }
    
    $("#hello-btn").click((route) => {
        fetch_data(route);
    });
</script>
```

When I click the button, fetch_data() would not run. When I run fetch_data() outside of the .click() function, it runs perfectly.

Any explanation as to why? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that on your #hello-btn click function you are defining `route` as the click event object and passing that as the route variable to be used in your function.

Try calling your function with the URL you want instead.

```js
let fetch_data = (route) => {
    fetch(route)
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then(data => $("#resp").text(data))
}

$("#hello-btn").click((e) => {
    fetch_data("/a-url");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="hello-btn">Say Hello!</button>
```

Comment: Tried suggested without success. :/

Comment: Would have to know what your API is outputting. You should try looking at your browser console to see what errors you are getting though.